# Laravel Eloquent Serialization: how to rename property?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

For example, I have User model extending Eloquent. In the database table, the column name is `user_id`.

How do I output the result as 'userId' after reading?

Comment: Are you only interested in a solution for one variable or do you want to rename everything from snake_case to camelCase?

Comment: @lukasgeiter I want to rename everything from snake_case to camelCase. But I would like to know how to do it for one variable as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Add single "aliases" using attribute accessors

You can use [attribute accessors](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) to create "new attributes":

```
public function getUserIdAttribute(){
    return $this->attributes['user_id'];
}
```

This allows you to access the value this way: `$user->userId`

Now let's add the value to array / JSON conversion:

```
protected $appends = array('userId');
```

And finally hide the ugly `user_id`:

```
protected $hidden = array('user_id');
```

### Convert all attribute names when converting to array / JSON

You can also use `toArray()` to change the all attribute names when converting the model into an array or JSON string.

```
public function toArray(){
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $camelArray = array();
    foreach($array as $name => $value){
        $camelArray[camel_case($name)] = $value;
    }
    return $camelArray;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! There is a small bug: `return $camelArray;` instead of `return $camelArray();`.

Comment: I wonder if there is something like http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations I used in Symfony 2.

Comment: There's nothing out of the box like this. Maybe there are packages for this and of course you could build it yourself ;)

Comment: This helped out so much on a project I'm working on. My server needed to mutate the attributes defined in the model so our trusted client-side app can use the returned Json. +1

Answer (score 3):

I do it in this way.

```
protected $remap_attrs = ['old_name' => 'new_name'];
public function toArray(){
    $array = parent::toArray();
    foreach($this->remap_attrs as $key => $new_key) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            $array[$new_key] = $array[$key];
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```