# How to change a key name in elequent colection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have these functions in my Category Class:

```php
...
    /**
     * Get the children of current category.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the nested children of current category.
     *
     * @return @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function childrenRecursive()
    {
        return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive');
    }

    /**
     * Get the category that depends with the given group name.
     *
     * @param string $group
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|null
     */
    public static function getTheCategory($group)
    {
        $root = Category::where('group', $group)->whereNull('parent_id')->first();
        return $root ? $root->childrenRecursive()->get() : null;
    }

   ...
```

When I call the `getTheCategory` function I get this result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Agricultural",
        "concise": "The category for agricultural products.",
        "created_at": "2019-12-17 18:01:05",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-17 18:01:05",
        "children_recursive": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Animal",
        "concise": "The category for animal products.",
        "created_at": "2019-12-17 18:01:05",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-17 18:01:05",
        "children_recursive": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "Handicrafts",
        "concise": "The category for handicrafts products.",
        "created_at": "2019-12-17 18:01:05",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-17 18:01:05",
        "children_recursive": []
    }
]
```

Now, how can I change the `children_recursive` to the `children`? I want the result like this:

```
[
  {
   "id": 2,
   "title": "Agricultural",
   "concise": "The category for agricultural products.",
   "created_at": "2019-12-17 18:01:05",
   "updated_at": "2019-12-17 18:01:05",
    "children": []
    },
  ...
]
```

Comment: using a mutator? it won't change the name but then you can access with children

Comment: Hi @AlbertoSinigaglia, yes I used a accessor but the result is same.

Comment: did you consider using `as` method? something like `$this->children()->with('childrenRecursive')->as('children');`

Comment: @shahabphp the `as` method is for belongsToMany and it renames the pivot object

Comment: @lagbox you are right, I thought it working as "alias". I think the stidiovip's comment which refer to add alias using attribute accessors is the answer.
Mohammad Ali Amini did it work for you?

Comment: Hi @shahabphp, no, it didn't work for me. I overridden the `toArray` function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use laravel's accessor and alias for doing this. See the decoumentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867569/laravel-eloquent-serialization-how-to-rename-property